# sharing servlet context across web applications in same server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have two servlets each in a separate web app running in the same container (Tomcat). Let the apps be app1 & app2, & servlets be serv1 & serv2.

I'm using serv1 (in app1) to call serv2(in app2).Im also trying to share a same session across these two servlets. Below is my code fragment.

**serv1 (app1)**:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://localhost:8080/app2/serv2").openConnection();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));  
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);  
String sessionId = session.getId();  
ServletContext myContext = getServletContext();
myContext.setAttribute("MYSHAREDSESSIONID", sessionId);
myContext.setAttribute("SHAREDSESSION", session);
```

**serv2( app2)**:

```
ServletContext callingContext = getServletContext().getContext("/app1");  
String jsessionId = (String)callingContext .getAttribute("MYSHAREDSESSIONID");
```

**server.xml**

```xml
<Host>
 <Context path="/app1" crossContext="true" />
 <Context path="/app2" crossContext="true" />
</Host>
```

The problem is Im getting null pointer exception in serv2 `getAttribute()`. The root cause is, the `getContext("/app1")` is returning ***null***. The context names are correct. I don't know why Im not able to retrieve the servlet context. I don't want to use cookies or url rewriting. Please help.

Comment: That `<Host>` should not go in `web.xml`. Since that would have resulted in a XML parsing error, I bet that you just typo'ed "web.xml"? Or do you *really* have it in the `web.xml` file and is the IDE's and/or servletcontainer's XML parser being too forgiving?

Comment: Im sorry. its not web.xml. its server.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks fine so far. Apparently it's been overridden by a `context.xml` maintained/generated elsewhere. You can read in the Tomcat's [`Context` configuration reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) about the rules. Do you for example have one in webapp's `/META-INF`? You should then define `crossContext` in there.

Or are you using an IDE like Eclipse to deploy the webapps or something? The IDE has then to be configured to not deploy into workspace metadata, but straight into Tomcat, otherwise Eclipse will use its own copy of `context.xml` (which you can find in *Servers* project). You can configure it in the server's preferences. Here's a screen from Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I configured the IDE to not to deploy into workspace metadata. I made it to deploy straight into tomcat itself. It worked....J

Answer (score 0):

According to J2EE every context has its own session management. You cannot share a session across two different servlet context.  You will need to pass the jessionid back and forth between context.

Comment: So do you say that setting crossContext=true won't work? Pls guide me in passing the jsessionid back and forth.

Comment: crossContext=true will work but it should be used cautiously. It is unsecure. Also you will be changing how the class loaders for your applications work. You should make sure that you understand tomcats class loader policies.