# Listening to change of context path in apache tomcat 7

Tags: java, apache, session, tomcat, servlets

I have 4 web applications added (deployed) to the apache tomcat 7 server. The server will host only these applications at any point in time i.e. tomcat is used only to host these 4 applications. And we're not deploying anything in the ROOT.

Now, I'm facing **issues** with **Session Management**.

Problem is that I'm getting different sessions for each of the application (which, if I'm correct, is because each application has a different container).

I can think of two possible approaches:

1. Session remains consistent across all applications. Therefore, it'll
   be easy to handle session.
2. I listen to the web server for application change (change of
   context/container, I presume) and then create, validate or
   invalidate session.

Here I have two questions corresponding to both the approaches.

1. Is it possible to have same session across all applications
   (containers)?
2. Is it possible to listen to apache for change of application
   (container)?

If answer is **YES** to any of the questions above, please guide on how I can do it? And if both approaches are **not possible**, please suggest a better approach?

**Present Approach:** I'm invalidating the session before switching to another application and after the switch is made, I'll create a new session for the corresponding application. Here, all will work as expected if the user browses through UI but problem persists if the user is in one application and then directly try to access another application through URL (web address).

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application containers and contexts are very much isolated, however there is opportunity to do cross context communication. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891817/sharing-servlet-context-across-web-applications-in-same-server) and [here](https://blog.imaginea.com/cross-context-communication-between-web-applications/).

Alternately, you can do your own custom session management using custom headers and interceptors

Comment: OK. But I think even with this approach, we'll not be able to use the same session object across different application contexts, right?

Comment: @GaganVerma yes, you cannot use the same session object, but you can validate the sessionid of one session in another session. This is hacky at best. What you are looking for is a typical SSO. You are better off implementing something like Tomcat inbuilt SSO valve or a framework like SAML